# Chinese Character Become?

Tags: android

I'm developing a mini library app for a non-profit group
I working with 
Android Studio 2 RC3 (23) + PHP + MySql + Asus Zenphone 5

so far everything work fine, no matter english or chinese character
everything is save correctly and display correct in the web and phone

But one of the user who using SAMSUNG(SM-J110G)
his chinese character will become ????? before storing inside database
So far i Toast it before post out (it show correct chinese character)

so anyone have any idea how should i solve is problem? or what make it change?
or what else should i consider with....

Many thanks

*PS SAMSUNG (J5) work fine also

Comment: character encoding problem

Comment: thanks for you reply keronconk, but can i know more about this? is due to my coding or the phone setting? any related references? i try few others SAMSUNG phone like J5/Note3, HONOR, ASUS, so far everyone work fine. thanks thanks thanks

Comment: ask your friend, his phone is SAMSUNG(SM-J110G), what language it have in language setting? I also met quite old phone not have support for language with another encoding, such as chinese, korean, japan, arabic, etc